# Image printing using with Flutter Thermal Printer

Tags: flutter, dart, printing, thermal-printer

I need to print a table with border in bluetooth thermal printer but its not achieved my passing bytes of text. So i decided to print image but i am facing quality issue after printing.

Package used : bluetooth_thermal_printer

My requirement to print

[image: Requirement]

```
  CapabilityProfile profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
    final generator = Generator(PaperSize.mm80, profile);
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('path');
    final Uint8List imgBytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();

    final img.Image image = img.decodeImage(imgBytes)!;
    bytes += generator.image(image);
```

This is how i tried to print the image

Comment: The resolution of receipt printers is around 180dpi to 203dpi. The resolution is significantly lower than that of printers connected to desktop PCs that print documents and photos. It's best to design your layout within the printer's hardware specifications.